# Deleting array pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

SO,

I am running into an error which I cannot figure out (unless my understanding is just incorrect).

I have the following code:

```
    int doubleSize=size*2;
    int *newArr = new int[doubleSize];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i ++) {
        newArr[i]=jon[i];
    }
    size*=2;

    display(newArr);
    jon=newArr;
    display(jon);
    delete[] newArr;
    display(jon);
```

After the first and second calls I get exactly what I want/expect. On the third display call the 0 and 1 indices are memory addresses, the rest of the values in the indices match the previous 2 calls. What could be causing this?

I also have another follow up question, with code as I have it, will not deleting jon[] cause the 'old' jon[] to stay in memory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

```
int *newArr = new int[size*2];
// now newArr is a pointer to a memory area
jon=newArr;
// now jon is a pointer to the same area, whatever jon pointed to before is leaked
delete[] newArr;
// now the memory area no longer exists
display(jon);
// using jon is now illegal, it has the address of a deleted memory area
```

Probably the right solution is:

```
int *newArr = new int[doubleSize]; // allocate a new area
for( int i=0; i<size; ++i ) {       // fill it in
    newArr[i] = jon[i];
}
delete [] jon; // get rid of the old area we don't need anymore
jon = newArr;  // now jon is linked to our brand new data in a brand new area
```

Comment: Hmm; would not deleting newArr not cause it to stay in memory? And every time the function is called with this code there would be more and more memory being used w/ these worthless values?       edit: I guess what I am asking would removing the delete[]newArr line make this code 'good'? It seems I would have problems every time this function is called, or would the new allocation of newArr overwrite the old?

Comment: @Dax: It's whatever `jon` pointed to before that stayed in memory but can no longer be used.  So you should release that memory (after reading it into the new area, of course).

Comment: @DaxDurax, wellcome to the wonderful world of C/C++, where _you_ are responsible of tracking what allocated values won't be used anymore, and can be safely destroyed. The so-called "higher-level languages" lift that burden (and the concomitant bugs) from the programmer, but at a high cost in memory usage and performance. If you are interested, there are garbage collectors for C/C++, look for Boehm.

Comment: Yeah, that was my original solution, however I have scope issues there (myArr is just temp in this function, jon isn't). I will have to look into the memcpy....thanks for the answer!

Comment: @vonbrand, Not really when you employ RAII.

Answer (score 3):

When you `delete[] newArr`, you're unallocating the memory at address `newArr`.  Since `jon` is also pointing to that same memory (because you set `jon = newArr`), the memory is being overwritten with some other values (probably in your `display` function).  What you need to do, is use some copy function (like [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/)) to copy the data to a newly allocated block at `jon`, not just point `jon` at the same spot as `newArr`.

Comment: Actually, it's probably `delete[]` that overwrites the content.  Many implementations do this intentionally to help catch use-after-free errors.  Others store bookkeeping data in freed regions.

Answer (score 1):

The last `display` call is trying to display `jon` that is the same as `newArr` - what you have just deleted! Thus the behaviour will be undefined.